# How to appear a button when focus ? Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

that's basically what I want, I need to make that button appears once the user focus on that input with the `ng-model=query`, so I know that there is an `ng-focus` directive, how can I use it ?

```
  <input type="search" ng-model="query">

  <!--this is the button I need to show once the user focus the input-->
  <div ng-show="query.length"
       ng-click="query = ''">
      Cancel
  </div>
```

there is the button that I to display once user focus on the input. So, instead of ng-show, what can I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in pure angular that would look like so :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>

  <input 
  type="search" 
  ng-model="query" 
  ng-focus="isSearchFocused=true"
  ng-blur="isSearchFocused=false"/>

<div 
  style="opacity:{{isSearchFocused && query.length?1:0}}"
  ng-click="query = ''">
  Cancel
</div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: The ng-app tag is missing in the jsbin.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer i cannot comment on other posts than mine (reputation :/ ). But the css solution should not use "display:none" because then the button does'nt work. Use visibility:hidden or opacity:0, making the button invisible but still clickable.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer : the best way to get the effect is putting the button right after the input in the html, then styling it to put it wherever you want, and use opacity:0 / opacity:1 instead of display:none to let the click on the button happen.
If you prefer to have it in separate div, see my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the + selector. This selects adjacent siblings.

```css
div.dat_div {
    display: none;
}
input[ng-model="query"]:focus + div.dat_div {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" ng-model="query">
 <!--this is the button I need to show once the user focus the input-->
<div class="dat_div" ng-show="query.length" ng-click="query = ''">
    Cancel
</div>
```

jQuery: `$('input[ng-model="query"]').on('focus',function(){$('div.dat_div').show();});`

Comment: this is great solution but what about if I have that in separate divs like this http://jsbin.com/luyanataqa/1/edit?html,css,output is not working now.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Unless with some magic, you can't go up the tree without JS. CSS4 is possibly going to implement parent selectors. I'm not familiar with angularjs but the above solution looks to implement back-end JS to accomplish this. I'll add the jquery solution for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate yourself from pure AngularJS and leverage CSS instead to do this action for you by using one of few methods. I would choose the plus (+) selector like so:

HTML

```
<input type="search" ng-model="query">

<!--this is the button I need to show once the user focus the input-->
<div class="hidden_btn" ng-show="query.length" ng-click="query = ''">
    Cancel
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden_btn { /* Hide this button initially */
    display: none;
}
input[ng-model="query"]:focus + .hidden_btn {
    display: block;
}
```

There are also other ways to go about it, which I will refer to you if you follow into this link: [AngularJS: show hide elements based on mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535383/angularjs-show-hide-elements-based-on-mouse-events)
Which you can easily leverage not only into your specific ng-model selector but onto any other similar methodology that you could bump into by relying on AngularJS.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: great but what about if I have it this way http://jsbin.com/luyanataqa/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: it's a matter of using your selectors the way you need them to work, in this case due to performance when relying on specificity I would keep the elements closer in terms of specificity. Which is why your provided JS bin isn't working.